# Vegan dining options on Maui

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, restaurants, hawaii, maui

Are any vegan dining options on the island of Maui? I suspect the vast majority of restaurants focus on seafood or something of that sort, but I wanted to see if any locals knew of some hidden vegan gem.

My question is specific to Maui and vegan, but I would entertain answers that reference other islands (as I'm sure we'll be on one of the other islands at some point). And if all else fails and there simply aren't any vegan options, I'll fall back to vegetarian options specific to Maui.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

happycow is a good resource for vegan and vegetarian food options when traveling. here's a link to hawaii...

http://www.happycow.net/north_america/usa/hawaii/

Comment: happy cow is the best reference I know for travelling vegetarians and vegans!

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of great vegan dining options in Maui, especially since this post was first written. All of the Hawaiian islands really pride themselves on having really fresh healthy food if that's what you are looking for.

Here is a great resource for vegan restaurants in Maui.

Top 10 Vegan Restaurants In Maui

https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g29220-zfz10697-Maui_Hawaii.html